# Error in model.frame.default object not found error

Tags: r

I have tried to run a regression with dependant variable `gdpgrowth` and independant variables `gdp60,popgrowth, school, literacy60, invest,` data from "AER" package "GrowthDJ". but i could run a regression without school and literacy60. but this command did not work:

```
myreg1<-lm(gdpgrowth~gdp60,popgrowth,invest,literacy60,school,data=GrowthDJ)
```

says

> object "literacy60" not found.

can anyone hepl me?
thanks.

Comment: Try `myreg1<-lm(gdpgrowth~gdp60+popgrowth+invest+literacy60+school,data=GrowthDJ)`

Comment: oh god) thanks a lot.

Comment: and one more thing. i have to create a dummy for oecd, oil and inter. ı know the command somename<-rep(1:0, x) don't know what to write instead of x. or can you show me another way. thanks.

Comment: only one question per question :-p